# Save selected map as image in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mapping

Is it possible to save selected objects such as map, legend, scale bar be saved as image without saving the whole layout in QGIS?

Comment: Could you describe what the final output would look like? Do you want a bank canvas with just the scalebar? Or do you want the scalebar standalone as an item?

Comment: I want a `.png` image which has size depending on the object. For example, if it was a scalebar, it will an image relative to the shape of the scalebar. So it is not a standalone item in the whole page setup.

Answer (score 2):

In the **layout manager** you're able to *exclude* elements from the export by clicking or unclickig them in the **Item panel**.

[image]

That's a manual possibility ..

I suppose that can be an answer to your question even if you have to **reframe** your picture afterwards ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe think in terms of Qt. If you can get a handle to the item's underlying QWidget, you could:

```
p = QPixmap.grabWindow(widget.winId())
p.save(filename, 'png')
```

The Widget would have to be at the front,  probably.